# Which one of these is broccoli?

Tags: identification, broccoli

Started some broccoli from seed and it's not something I often plant. Two cells both plants look different. I'm pretty sure the one I planted in the raised bed is the broccoli because there was another similar looking plant growing in another cell. Thinking it might be a weed.  Also the one I planted has purplish stems which matches the description of the plant.

Any idea if I got the broccoli correct and what the other plant might be? The variety of broccoli is purple sprouting.

If it helps, the other similar plant I saw was growing in an adjacent cell where I had started some mesclun mix lettuce seeds. Other nearby cells had mustard tatsoi, italian chicory.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like lambs quarter in the pot and some sort of brassica in the ground... if you planted broccoli, then that is it...

Comment: Looked at some photos online of lamb's quarter and that seems to be right. Not something I think I've ever had before and not something I want. Have enough random amaranth I don't mind because I eat them. Don't want more. Must have been in the potting mix. I'm going to smother it with hot grease, burn it with fire and then mail the ashes to a random address I find on another content just to be on the safe side.

Comment: That is the correct response to lambsquarter.

Comment: I'll just throw out there that lambsquarter is also edible, so you could pull and just mix it in with some spinach. Might be an easier way of getting rid of it than the method you suggested. ;)

Comment: as @michelle has mentioned it is edible, but it is high in oxalate... it was was probably domesticated at least 3 different times, in eastern north america, mexico and europe, the seeds used as a psudo-cereal.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure about the plant in the pot, but the one in the bed definetely is a cabbage. There are a few cabbages that look remarkably similar at this stage, kohlrabi, for example. Based on what you write, this is your broccoli.

The mysterious seedling is not tatsoi, because this has rounded leaves right from the start.

Italian chicory is out, too, because none of it's types have a central stem, all leaves emerge from the center point.

So it's either something out of your mesclun mix (whatever this specific mix contains, doesn't look like lettuce, though), or you have carefully nurtured a weed.

Comment: Yeah it didn't look like any of the other seeds I planted in that tray but thought Id throw that in there since another weed popped up in an adjacent cell. I only planted two cells of broccoli. One to plant and one as a spare unless I could find room. I think I even thinned out the actual broccoli plant from that cell without realizing it because that one was bigger.